# ASP.Net Dropdown List is not throwing an error

Tags: asp.net

I am having problems with dropdown lists NOT throwing an error with the following code in ASP.Net 4.0

the dropdown list is empty to start. The page in question is a simple test page containing no code besides the lines below in Page_Load.

```
ddlTest.Items.Add(new ListItem("test","test"));
ddlTest.SelectedValue = "Fail";
```

When I load the page, the DDL displays "test" as the only item (as expected) and no error is thrown. I thought an error would be thrown with something like "item 'Fail' does not exist"

I have tested the code both, inside an if (!IsPostBack) block and outside of it. The results are the same.

Does this make sense? I don't understand why this is not throwing an error. Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It will only throw an exception if there are no items in ddlTest, otherwise it just doesn't find the value.

You can always do this first if you are trying to find out if the item exists in the list:

```
if (ddlTest.Items.FindByValue("Fail") != null)
  ddlTest.SelectedValue = "Fail";
else
  //item doesn't exist, do something meaningful here
```

Comment: Are you sure about that? [MSDN would suggest otherwise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx)

Comment: Ok, in this case I would be correct since no postback was performed, however, if in fact a postback occurs, you will get an exception.  Good catch.